# for loop to set javascript variable = to a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, loops, variables

I am working on a project that requires create hundreds of variables in javascript with PHP values.  I can write each one line by line like so:

```
var M1 = <?php echo json_encode($$mn[0]); ?>;
var M2 = <?php echo json_encode($$mn[1]); ?>;
var M3 = <?php echo json_encode($$mn[2]); ?>;
```

As I said there are hundreds of these though and if it is possible to do in a loop I would be very interested in learning.  I have searched all over and can't find a direct answer.  It may very well be that this is not possible.  I am new to coding and still learning what certain code can and cannot do.

Any insight or direction on this topic would be greatly appreciated!

If this is not an option is it possible to use an array index for the javascript variable name?  I have created an array for the JS and PHP.  The PHP works fine above but if I try to use an array index for the JS like below, it breaks:

```
var mcirc[0] = <?php echo json_encode($$mn[0]); ?>;
```

I have output the array and the values are coming up correctly but when I run this I get the message:

```
[object HTMLDivElement]
```

instead of the actually value that should show up.

UPDATE

$mn array:

```
for ($m1 = 1; $m1 < 6; $m1++) {
    $mn[] = 'M'.$m1;
}
```

UPDATE

Select SQL creating array:

```
$sqlMC = "SELECT * FROM tblmaincircles";
$result = $conn->query($sqlMC);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $$row["mcID"]= $row["mcName"];
}
```

The array for mcID looks like this:

```
M1 = "text1"
M2 = "text2"
M3 = "text3"
M4 = "text4"
M5 = "text5"
```

UPDATE

end result desired:

```
var M1 = "text1";
var M2 = "text2";
var M3 = "text3";
var M4 = "text4";
var M5 = "text5";
```

Where "text1, ...2, ...3, ...4, ...5" are coming from the MySQL database.

UPDATE

Here is the final code that got this working:

```
$sqlMC = "SELECT mcID, mcName FROM tblmaincircles";
$result = $conn->query($sqlMC);


    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $mcID[] = $row["mcID"];
        $mcName[] = $row["mcName"];
}


<?php for ($m1 = 0; $m1 <5; $m1++) { ?>
    var <?php echo $mcID[$m1]; ?> = <?php echo json_encode($mcName[$m1]); ?>;
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: variable variables? that's hideiously ugly. why not an array? `var M = <?php  echo json_encode($m_array); ?>`? and exactly what is this $mn` array in the first place?

Comment: And why are you variabling the variable `$mn` ? Why not `json_encode` the entire `$mn`?

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for the input.  As I said I am new and variable variables is the what I found to work to pull an indexed value.  If there is a better way I am all for it but I would prefer to stay on topic.  I have updated the question to include the `$mn` array.

Comment: variable variables are never the solution to anything. they're merely the cause of hair loss (e.g. ripping it out and screaming when you try to debug the mess they cause).

Comment: @frz3993 I am using variable variables because if I use just `$mn` it will return the value "M1" instead of "text of M1".

Comment: @MarcB I am using the variable variables to access the array created from my sql Select statement.  I will include that in the question as well.  I am still learning so I am always open to suggestions.

Comment: So the `M1,M2,M3...` are the `mcID`s? And you want the `$key => $value` to be like `['M1' =>  'text1']`? Can you show an example of the end result you want to achieve? I'm suspecting you don't even need the `json_encode`.

Comment: but it's an array. you don't need variable variables. `result[7]['somefield']` is far easier to maintain/carry-around than `result7['somefield']`. you end up with one single variable (`result`), instead of a a variable-per-row. if you have a million records, you end up with a million variables.

Comment: [There may be valid use cases of variable variables](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/154588/are-there-any-good-use-cases-for-variable-variables). This not not one of them.

Comment: @frz3993 I have included the desired result in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your query part, declare a variable to hold the result that you want. I'm assuming the `M1` is `mcID` in your table and `text1` is the `mcName`. For example:

```
$sqlMC = "SELECT * FROM tblmaincircles";
$result = $conn->query($sqlMC);

$mac = [];//or $mac = array(); Depends on your PHP version.

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $mac[$row["mcID"]] = $row["mcName"];
}
```

And then, iterate through the `$mac` array with `foreach` loop. I'm assuming you are using PHP codes within HTML. The `$key` will be the `mcID` and the  `$value` will be the `mcName`.

```
//php tag for the foreach opening
<?php foreach ($mac as $key => $value) { ?>

    var <?php echo $key; ?> = <?php echo "'$value';"; ?>

//php tag for the foreach closing
<?php } ?>
```

OR, if you want to use javascript associative array.

```
var macJs = {};

<?php foreach ($mac as $key => $value) { ?>

    macJs.<?php echo $key; ?> = <?php echo "'$value';"; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

And you can access the element like this in javascript `macJs.M1`.

Comment: This is really close to what I want!  The first block of code that includes `$mac[$row["mcID"]]= $row["mcname"];` is only storing the last value in the array.  I found this out by using `var_dump` where I received the message `array (size=1) 'M5' => string 'text5'`  why would it only be returning the last value in the array instead of all of them?

Comment: @CraigHowell, it shouldn't. Unless all of the rows have the same `mcID`.

Comment: I just looked at the database and the are all seperate `M1, M2, M3, M4, M5`

Comment: I mean update into your question how you do that part. Another thing that can cause it is declaring `$mac = [];` inside the loop, where on each iteration the variable will be emptied and finally only the last row remains @CraigHowell.

Comment: I found the problem and now the dump is showing all 5 circles but now the loop is not working.  I am getting the generic text `object HTMLdivElement` @frz3993

Comment: [object HTMLdivElement] means the javascript variable that you used has been assigned with a html element. Maybe an overlapped assignment

Comment: I was able to get this working.  I had to make a tweak to my sql select statement.  I will add the final answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put JSON into variable

```
var json = <?php echo json_encode($$mn); ?>;
```

And then process the JSON way you want:

eg.

```
var json=[{key:someValue},
          {key:someValue2},
          {key:someValue3}
         ];

json.forEach(function(a){
  console.log(a.key);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSON to 'export' your objects/array through different languages, in that case:

```
var json = '<?= json_encode($your_array); ?>';
```

After this you can parse this Json, what should return your array:

```
var your_array = JSON.parse(json);
```